# Why does this nested ArrayList code throw an exception?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(5);
for (int i = 0 ; i < a.size() ; i++){
    a.set(i, new ArrayList<Integer>(10));
}
System.out.println(a.get(a.size()-1).get(9)); //exception thrown
```

The above snippet throws an exception in the printing part. Why?

Comment: please specify the exception.  (most likely an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.)

Comment: I presume you tried to mimic a multi-dimensional int array using ArrayLists.

Answer (score 19):

You set only the capacity of the outer/inner ArrayLists. They are still empty.
And your loop doesn't even execute because `a.size()` is 0.
You need a second inner loop to add elements to them.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
    List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        lst.add(j);
    }   
    a.add(lst);
}
System.out.println(a.get(a.size()-1).get(9));
```

**Edit:** And watch out for `a.set(i, ...)`. It throws exception if i >= a.size().

Comment: Indent it with four spaces and you don't have to escape <'s. I just did it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you put

```
System.out.println(a.size());
```

after your first line, you'll see that the size of your outer array is zero.  Thus the loop executes zero times, thus after the loop you are requesting the -1th element of a - and that's an error.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `new ArrayList<Integer>(10)`, the "10" just indicates the initial capacity.  It's still an empty list, and you can't call `get(9)` on it.

Answer (score 1):

a is an empty list so a.size() = 0 so in a.get(a.size()-1) the expression (a.size() - 1) is -1 so a.get(-1) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

You've created empty array lists in the for loop, so trying access any element in them return null to System.out.println()

*edit*
Sorry, wont' return null but instead throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `new ArrayList(10)` creates an **empty** ArrayList with its internal backing array initially set to size 10. The ArrayList is empty until you add elements to it. The constructor allows you specify the initial internal size as an optimization measure.